# Why will my custom "Entries" field not display anything?

Tags: entries-field

In my entry template I have the following...

```
{% set entry95 = entry.story1995 %}
{{ entry95.title }}
```

And this displays nothing. Debug mode is on and no errors are showing. The handle for the field is set properly. Other fields for the main entry are showing up, but nothing from this custom Entries field.

I can't figure out what I could be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the entry in a for loop. Because even if there's only one entry linked to, it could still potentially be multiple entries!

```
{% for entry95 in entry.story1995 %}
    {{ entry95.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That, or `{% set entry95 = entry.story1995.first() %}`

Comment: Ha! Sorry for the noise. I banged my head over this for hours. Ugh. As soon as I post the question I figure it out. Ain't that typical.